# Joining Google and a Facebook contact on Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, contacts

I am trying to write an application that join Google and Android contacts for Android,
but I can't seem to find the facebook contacts in the entire raw_contacts table.

How do I find the Facebook contacts (on the phone's database, not the Facebook API)
and secondly, how do I join two contacts?

I should also note that I am trying to build an application that synchronises Android contacts with uncombined Facebook contacts and after that, sets the Google contact's photo the the full resolution image from the Facebook site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an extension, similar to the core Android SDK, but no, here is what you need to do:

1. Go to `github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk`
2. Download the Facebook directory ONLY! The other directories are only examples.
3. Put the files from the `src` (you can copy the drawables too, if you want to) in the package, you are currently working with
4. You are good to go; you can now use the Facebook "SDK"

See also the example `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook`. Download it. It is working a example provided by Facebook that contains source code of friend list.

**And** *[Android OAuth with Google contacts tutorial with full source code](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html)*  will help you to fetch Google contacts.